# Parsing data from dynamic webpage with injected content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to inject an iframe with my chrome extension and I'm having difficulty injecting it on a particular site. If I check the Network tab in chrome I can see that the main file looks something like this:

```
<body>
     <app-root></app-root>
     <script src="runtime.2ed1a126f5b940f24835.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.71c81a25540b98493cde.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills.6ff9102ee8a3b26f6c56.js" defer></script><script src="scripts.8b70b835e8cebce8bff7.js" defer></script><script src="main.be986289c2a19031ee6d.js" defer></script></body>
</html>
```

But if I inspect element(F12) the webpage after a second the source code of the page looks entierly different. Something like this:

```
<body class="support-pages">
     <app-root _nghost-hna-c0="" ng-version="8.2.14">
          <router-outlet _ngcontent-hna-c0=""></router-outlet>
          <app-home class="ng-star-inserted">
               <div class="layout-wrapper"><app-header>
etc...
```

My injection code works on a page that is written in pure html but not on this one since it dynamically loads and updates the DOM? I see in console that it prints null when I try to grab a particular element via getElementByXpath. Can I somehow wait until it's finished loading(I'm guessing not since it's done at runtime) and then inject the code or is there a particular API endpoint that I could use.

My current code that works on normal html pages but not this particular dynamic one:

```
function Inject(width, height){
    var path = document.getElementsByClassName("content-box");
    path.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin", '<div class="widget"><a href="https://somelink.com?width=" + width + "&height=" + height>Quick Connect</a></div>');
}
```

Thanks for the help,
Sick

Comment: Is it on a certain website only? Do your other websites have this class "content-box"? Because not all websites have "content-box". If you want it on all websites, try to use the -> path = document.body; . See my answer.

Comment: In addition to the advice above, which is entirely correct: modern sites build their DOM dynamically using scripts, so you can use MutationObserver to detect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample **MutationObserver**.

matches.js

```js
const onMutation = (mutations) => {
  mo.disconnect();

  for (const { addedNodes } of mutations) {
    for (const node of addedNodes) {
      if (node.className == "content-box") {
        node.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin", "<div>hoge</div>");
      }
    }
  }

  observe();
}

const observe = () => {
  mo.observe(document, {
    subtree: true,
    childList: true,
  });
}

const mo = new MutationObserver(onMutation);

observe();
```

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "MutationObserver",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "matches.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Inject(width, height){
  var bo = document.body;
  let html = '<div class="widget"><a href="https://somelink.com?width="' + width + '"&height="' + height + '">Quick Connect</a></div>';
  bo.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin", html);
}
Inject(200,100);
```